# How to open the Sidebar so that it sits on over of the main information page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sidebar

My website has a sidebar (FiltersSideBar in my code) with filters. The sidebar is on the left.

I also made a functionality that would hide the Sidebar at certain sizes of the browser window. The sidebar hides and a button appears with which (I assume) Sidebar can be opened again.

This is where I have a problem. I can't figure out how to open the Sidebar so that it sits on over of the main information page.

App.js

```
export default function App() {
    const [filters, setFilters] = useState({.....})
    const size = WindowSize();   
    const [setHideSidebar] = useState(false);
 
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Header/>
                <button style={{display: size.width > 600 ? "none" : "inline"}}
                        onClick={() => {setHideSidebar((prev) => !prev);}}>Toggle Sidebar
                </button>
                <AppContext.Provider value={{ filters, setFilters}}>
                    <div style={{display: 'flex'}} >
                        {size.width > 600 && <FiltersSideBar />}
                        <Routes>
                           <Route exact path='/devices/:deviceId/:userId/:sessionId' element={<Records />} />
                            <Route exact path='/devices/:deviceId/:userId/:sessionId/:recordId' element={<Record />} />
                            <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/devices" replace />} />
                        </Routes>
                    </div>
                </AppContext.Provider>
                <Footer />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

FiltersSideBar.jsx

```
export default function FiltersSideBar() {
    return (
        <CardContent>
            <Table>
                <TableBody>
                  ......
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </CardContent>
    );
}
```

Comment: Maybe using `z-index` will resolve your problem - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by actually using the value set by `setHideSidebar`

```js
const [filters, setFilters] = useState({.....})
const size = WindowSize();
// Actually use the state here
const [hideSidebar, setHideSidebar] = useState(true);
```

And then below that, where you are checking if the sidebar can be shown above a certain width, add the following

```js
{size.width > 600 && <FiltersSideBar />}
{size.width <= 600 && !hideSidebar && <FiltersSideBar className="overlay" />}
```

You'll need to augment your `FiltersSideBar` component to use the `className` when it's available:

```js
export default function FiltersSideBar(props) {
    return (
        <CardContent className={props.className}>
            {/* ... */}
        </CardContent>
    );
}
```

And also you'll need to add the following css somewhere

```css
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't understand your phrase "You'll need to augment your FiltersSideBar component to use the className when it's available". What should I add to this component?

Comment: @Paul you'll need to change it so that the containing element adds the value in `className` to the `className` attribute of your main element in `FiltersSideBar`. You can share this component code if you like and I'll add how you can add the `className` prop.

Comment: Yes, I will be grateful to you. I added FiltersSideBar

Comment: Sorry for the delay, went to eat, now, @Paul I need to know where you are getting `CardContent` from, this I know the types of props I can pass it.

Comment: Thanks, it works. This is probably what I was looking for. I'm leaving now, and then I'll continue my work. Can I contact you if I have minor questions?